# Uncaught TypeError: r.zoom is not a function jQuery Wordpress Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.zoom is not a function
at j (jet-woo-product-gallery.min.js?ver=1.3.0:1)
at Object.productGallery (jet-woo-product-gallery.min.js?ver=1.3.0:1)
at t.init (jet-woo-product-gallery.min.js?ver=1.3.0:1)
at swiper.min.js?ver=5.3.6:13
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at swiper.min.js?ver=5.3.6:13
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at t.l.emit (swiper.min.js?ver=5.3.6:13)
at t.init (swiper.min.js?ver=5.3.6:13)
at new t (swiper.min.js?ver=5.3.6:13)
```

Hello developers please help I m not able to resolve this issue and please let me know why this is happened. Thiss issue Occured after i smush the website Using wp Rocket but when i deactivated my website get error on footer. Please check https://e-spacedecor.com/product/espace-truffel-sofa/ Please check the Footerenter code here

Comment: Clear your WP Rocket cache, then disable it. WP Rocket gives a bunch of warnings when minifying and combining scripts that this will occur. This is nothing we can help with, since WP Rocket is causing it.

Comment: I was Disabled but then too issue not resolved and shows the same on entire website. i dont know what to do

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, since I don't get any of the errors you are getting.